# AWS Terraform “Error: uploading object to S3 bucket : AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs status code: 400“

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I’m trying to deploy a website using AWS S3 but I keep getting this error “Error: uploading object to S3 bucket : AccessControlListNotSupported: The bucket does not allow ACLs status code: 400”

This is my code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "web-server-${random_pet.petname.id}"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "s3_config" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id

    index_document {
        suffix = "index.html"
    }

    error_document {
        key = "error.html"
    }

    depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket_acl.s3_acl ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "s3_ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "s3_acl" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.s3_ownership,
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.s3_access,
  ]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  acl    = "public-read"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  for_each = fileset("assets", "**")

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  key    = each.key
  source = "assets/${each.key}"
  acl = "public-read"
  etag = filemd5("assets/${each.key}")
#   content_type = lookup(local.content_type_map, split(".", "assets/${each.value}")[1], "text/html")
}
```

And I checked the object ownership and I think I have the good settings:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any kind of a bucket policy applied?

Comment: What is your S3 source? I suspect your problem originates from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-s3-automatically-enable-block-public-access-disable-access-control-lists-buckets-april-2023/).

Comment: Could it be because it tries to upload the object before the ACL is in place?? maybe add a `depends_on` to the resource `aws_s3_object` to create a dependency on the `aws_s3_bucket_acl`

Comment: Hello everyone, I'd like to thank you for your help. Looking more closely at the logs I noticed (@HelderSepulveda was right too) that terraform was trying to upload objects even before the acl was set up. The problem was solved once I had set up the dependency on the aws_s3_object resource.